# Changing dates in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date

Consider a table **DateDetails** having a column **effectiveDate**.
  I want to write an update query such that :

```
  if effectiveDate > "first day of the month" then
         ->set it to "first day of the month"
```

something like :

```
update DateDetails
set effectiveDate = (start of the month)
where effectiveDate > (start of the month)
```

effectiveDate is of type DATE. Also the day, month, year could be any:12-JAN-2013 or 24-DEC-2056
How can I write this?

Comment: I ran the query jaczes suggested. Got an error:Error report: SQL Error: ORA-00904: "DATE_FORMAT": invalid identifier 00904. 00000 - "%s: invalid identifier".. Any ideas?..

Comment: because it's for MYSQL not for ORACLE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update DateDetails
set effectiveDate = DATE_FORMAT(start_date ,'01-%b-%Y')
where effectiveDate > start_date;
```

Will change all dates to 1st day of month of efffective date

```
update DateDetails
set effectiveDate = DATE_FORMAT(effectiveDate ,'01-%b-%Y');
```

Comment: sorry my question was a bit misleading.. there is no column as start_date. There is just 1 column named effectiveDate.. i have updated my question

Comment: @digvijay The solution still applies. All it does, is set the Day Part to "1" on whatever date you want. Just replace start_date with effectiveDate and remove the condition.

Comment: @digvijay You can replace start_date by effectiveDate and get rid of `WHERE`

Comment: you don't need the where clause because that compares dates on a scale over all time, but the person asking the question only want to test whether the day of the month is greater than one.  In this example, where does "start date" come from, and what happens if effectiveDate just happens to be set to be significantly less than it (e.g. several months earlier).

Comment: @AgilePro effectiveDate needs to be compared only with itself in the same month. There is no column called "startDate". I just wrote the question a bit wrong

Comment: @jaczes So can I write my final query as : 'update DateDetails
set effectiveDate = DATE_FORMAT(effectiveDate ,'01-%b-%Y') where effectiveDate > DATE_FORMAT(effectiveDate ,'01-%b-%Y')'

Comment: @digvijay YES, but `Where` condition is not necessary. All records would have 01-MMM-YYYY format. Those who are first days won't be updated.

Comment: I am getting an error :Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "DATE_FORMAT": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: because it's for MYSQL not for ORACLE!

Comment: TO_CHAR(<date>, '01-MON-YYYY')

Comment: I tried something like this:effectiveDate = TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(effectiveDate, '01-MON-YYYY'),'01-MON-YYYY')... It flashes ORA-01821: date format not recognized
01821. 00000 -  "date format not recognized"..

Comment: ORCL isn't the same as MYSQL that should be like `effectiveDate ='01-'||to_char(effectiveDate, 'MON-YYYY')`

Answer (score 0):

```
update DateDetails
set effectiveDate = DATE_FORMAT(effectiveDate, '01-%b-%Y')
where effectiveDate > DATE_FORMAT(effectiveDate, '01-%b-%Y');
```